# .CSHTML on MAMP?

Tags: razor, mamp

Working on OSX platform, a coworker ask me to do some modification on a website he is working on.

He is a pro .NET so he send me .cshtml file that I never heard about it.

I try the simple drag and drop inside htdocs and it's not working.

Before downloading all the VM/iso to run W10 on my machine, I would like to know if I have to setup up something on MAMP to make it works ?

Answer (score 0):

If the cshtml file is work. You can running it in `Visual Studio Code` .

reference:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html

download:
https://www.visualstudio.com/